# What law in Geometry was used to find this answer?

Tags: trigonometry

My question is kind of complicated. I just don't understand how they got this. Can you follow me through the steps on how to finding this answer?

"The accompanying diagram shows the plans for a cell-phone tower that is to be built near a busy highway. Find the height of the tower, to the nearest foot.

x/ sin32 = 100/ sin 33

x= 100 sin 32/ sin 33

x= 97.3

sin 65= T/ 97.3

T= 88

[image]

$$\begin{align*}
&\frac{x}{\sin 32} = \frac{100}{\sin 33}\\\\
&x=\frac{100\sin 32}{\sin 33}\\\\
&x=97.3\\\\
&{\sin 65}= \frac{T}{ 97.3 }\\\\
&T= 88\\\\
\end{align*}$$

I am preparing for my regents in June and I came across this question while studying. I don't understand any of this. We haven't even learned this!

Comment: The [Law of Sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines).

Comment: For future reference, there’s a MathJax tutorial [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: The first line of equations comes from the Law of Sines applied to the obtuse triangle in the left. The second line of equations comes from definition of sine (or if you prefer, the Law of Sines) applied to the right triangle on the right.

Answer (score 1):

What has been used to find $x$ or $X$  is *the Law of Sines*.

Combining the steps it helps to find the height of the tower from:

TowerHeight = h, and  $100 = h( \cot 32^0 -\cot 65^0 ). $